# Is it possible to keep the img tags and ONLY THE TEXT of other tags with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this example of Html code:

```
<br>Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png"><br><p class="MsoNormal">Adios.</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b>Si</b></p><img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">
```

What I am trying to do without any positive results is to keep the text only but with the img tags like this:

```
Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png">Adios.Si<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">
```

I need some ideas or solutions for this, this string is dynamic, if I could keep br tags also it would be awesome, I tried a lot of things without successfull.

Comment: Can you show your best attempt(s)? That way we might show you where you went wrong, so you can learn from the failure as well as from working code that we show and share with you.

Comment: Take all images to array, replace them with something like `[IMG1]`, do `.text()`, replace `[IMG1]` back to actual image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex to split the string into an array containing only the text and image parts and then join the resulting array, like so:

```js
const removeTags = (html) => html.split(/<(?!img)[^>]*>/).join('');

const testString = '<br>Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png"><br><p class="MsoNormal">Adios.</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b>Si</b></p><img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">';

const result = removeTags(testString);
```

The magic here relies on the regex expression inside the removeTags function, `<(?!img)[^>]*>`, in which we are selecting all text enclosed in between less and greater than brackets, except for the cases where the tag begins with "img".

Snippet:

```js
const removeTags = (html) => html.split(/<(?!img)[^>]*>/).join('');
const testString = '<br>Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png"><br><p class="MsoNormal">Adios.</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b>Si</b></p><img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">';
const result = removeTags(testString);
document.getElementById('finalResult').innerText = result;
```

```html
<style>p{font-family:sans-serif}pre{background-color:#eee;padding:5px;border-radius:4px;white-space:pre-line}</style>

<p>Initial:</p>

<pre>
&lt;br&gt;Hola&lt;img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png"&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;p class="MsoNormal"&gt;Adios.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;b&gt;Si&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png"&gt;
</pre>

<p>Result:</p>

<pre id="finalResult">
</pre>
```

Comment: is it possible to keep the br tags also with that split?

Comment: @J.Mo yep, just add a pipe br to the negative lookahead and you're good to go: `removeTags = (html) => html.split(/<(?!img|br)[^>]*>/).join('');`

Comment: @J.Mo glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, though I can't help but feel it could be optimised, is as below:

```
// named function, declared using const and defined using
// Arrow function syntax; here the function receives two
// arguments, the 'haystack' a String of HTML that you want
// to process, and an Object to update the settings/behaviour:
const retainOnly = (haystack, opts) => {

  // an Object that defines the default behaviour of the
  // function:
  // keep:     an Array of element-names ('img','div','br'...)
  //           that you want to retain in the String, and
  // keepText: a Boolean true/false; true if you wish to
  //           retain textNodes, false if you wish to remove
  //           them.
  let settings = {
      'keep': ['img'],
      'keepText': true
    },

    // a <div> element in which to place the String of
    // HTML, in order to use DOM methods rather than
    // parsing HTML with regular expressions (see the
    // bibliography):
    temp = document.createElement('div');

  // using Object.keys() to return an Array of the iterable
  // keys of the opts Object, or an empty Object-literal,
  // to update the default settings Object; we use
  // Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the Array of
  // keys, again using an Arrow function:
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(

    // the 'key' is passed into the function, and is a 
    // reference to the current key of the Array of keys
    // over which we're iterating; in the function we
    // set the property-value of the key of the settings
    // Object to the value held in the property-value of
    // the opts Object:
    (key) => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  // setting the innerHTML of the created <div>:
  temp.innerHTML = haystack;

  // caching the childNodes of the <div> as an Array of
  // Nodes:
  let children = [...temp.childNodes];

  // here we use a for...of loop to iterate over the
  // Array of childNodes in the 'children' variable:
  for (let child of children) {

    // if the child has a nodeType of 1 (and is therefore
    // an HTMLElement, and the lower-cased tagName of that
    // child is not included in the settings.keep Array:
    if (child.nodeType === 1 && !settings.keep.includes(child.tagName.toLowerCase())) {

      // we replace that childNode using the
      // childNode.replaceWith() method, passing in
      // that child's innerHTML as the String, and
      // also the opts Object passed to this function:
      child.replaceWith(retainOnly(child.innerHTML, opts));
    }

    // otherwise if the child's nodeType is equal to 3 and
    // settings.keepText is equal to false (so we don't wish
    // to retain textNodes):
    else if (child.nodeType === 3 && settings.keepText === false) {
      // we use parentNode.removeChild() to remove that child:
      child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
  }

  // once that processing is completed we return the
  // temp.innerHTML String to the calling context
  // (returning the innerHTML is also how the recursion
  // works in this function):
  return temp.innerHTML;

};

// your string of HTML defined as a template-literal:
let HTMLString = `<br>Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png"><br><p class="MsoNormal">Adios.</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b>Si</b></p><img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">`,

// caching the result of calling the function:
processed = retainOnly(HTMLString);

// outputting the processed HTMLString to the console:
console.log(processed)
// 'Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png">Adios.Si<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">'
```

```js
const retainOnly = (haystack, opts) => {
  let settings = {
      'keep': ['img'],
      'keepText': true
    },
    temp = document.createElement('div');

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(
    (key) => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  temp.innerHTML = haystack;

  let children = [...temp.childNodes];

  for (let child of children) {
    if (child.nodeType === 1 && !settings.keep.includes(child.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
      child.replaceWith(retainOnly(child.innerHTML, opts));
    }
    if (child.nodeType === 3 && settings.keepText === false) {
      child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
  }
  return temp.innerHTML;

};
let HTMLString = `<br>Hola<img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F44B.png"><br><p class="MsoNormal">Adios.</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b>Si</b></p><img class="emoji" src=".../_images/emoji/1F4AA.png">`;

let processed = retainOnly(HTMLString);
console.log(processed)
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).
- [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
- [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [Spread syntax `[...Iterable]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Bibliography:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/82548;) see the accepted answer.